# Overwriting Multiple rows in a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have csv file in which I am storing 5 rows by running my python script.
I want to overwrite the rows when 6th time or nth time my script run.and delete the 1st row
My csv looks like this:

Timestamp,Offset,lag
1441365363,601,1
1441365363,602,2
1441365371,603,3
1441365378,604,4
1441375562,605,0

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use `line_number % 5` when you write to your file. Show us some code.